# Open Ubuntu from R and run a bash script : command not found (even if PATH is correctly set)

Tags: r, linux, bash, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to automatize a pipeline written on Rstudio.
During the process, I need to use Ubuntu commands : gtf2bed and halLiftover.

I wrote a bash script which basically a list of commands lines like below :

```
#!/bin/bash

## Step 6 : Use the alignment file to find the alignment between two neighboring species on the phylogenetic tree based on the reconfigured coordinates above

#Convert into bed file 
gtf2bed < reconfigured_singletons_bovis.gtf > reconfigured_singletons_bovis.bed
gtf2bed < reconfigured_singletons_becei.gtf > reconfigured_singletons_becei.bed
gtf2bed < reconfigured_singletons_panamensis.gtf > reconfigured_singletons_panamensis.bed
gtf2bed < reconfigured_singletons_inopinata.gtf > reconfigured_singletons_inopinata.bed
gtf2bed < reconfigured_singletons_elegans.gtf > reconfigured_singletons_elegans.bed
gtf2bed < reconfigured_singletons_tropicalis.gtf > reconfigured_singletons_tropicalis.bed
gtf2bed < reconfigured_singletons_remanei.gtf > reconfigured_singletons_remanei.bed
gtf2bed < reconfigured_singletons_latens.gtf > reconfigured_singletons_latens.bed
gtf2bed < reconfigured_singletons_tribulationis.gtf > reconfigured_singletons_tribulationis.bed
gtf2bed < reconfigured_singletons_briggsae.gtf > reconfigured_singletons_briggsae.bed
gtf2bed < reconfigured_singletons_nigoni.gtf > reconfigured_singletons_nigoni.bed


#Do a halLiftover to find the aligned regions according the order of the tree 
halLiftover evolver_Caenorhabditis.hal --outPSLWithName caenorhabditis_bovis reconfigured_singletons_bovis.bed caenorhabditis_becei bovis_becei.psl --bedType 4
halLiftover evolver_Caenorhabditis.hal --outPSLWithName caenorhabditis_becei reconfigured_singletons_becei.bed caenorhabditis_panamensis becei_panamensis.psl --bedType 4
halLiftover evolver_Caenorhabditis.hal --outPSLWithName caenorhabditis_panamensis reconfigured_singletons_panamensis.bed caenorhabditis_inopinata panamensis_inopinata.psl --bedType 4
halLiftover evolver_Caenorhabditis.hal --outPSLWithName caenorhabditis_inopinata reconfigured_singletons_inopinata.bed caenorhabditis_elegans inopinata_elegans.psl --bedType 4
halLiftover evolver_Caenorhabditis.hal --outPSLWithName caenorhabditis_elegans reconfigured_singletons_elegans.bed caenorhabditis_tropicalis elegans_tropicalis.psl --bedType 4
halLiftover evolver_Caenorhabditis.hal --outPSLWithName caenorhabditis_tropicalis reconfigured_singletons_tropicalis.bed caenorhabditis_remanei tropicalis_remanei.psl --bedType 4
halLiftover evolver_Caenorhabditis.hal --outPSLWithName caenorhabditis_remanei reconfigured_singletons_remanei.bed caenorhabditis_latens remanei_latens.psl --bedType 4
halLiftover evolver_Caenorhabditis.hal --outPSLWithName caenorhabditis_latens reconfigured_singletons_latens.bed caenorhabditis_tribulationis latens_tribulationis.psl --bedType 4
halLiftover evolver_Caenorhabditis.hal --outPSLWithName caenorhabditis_tribulationis reconfigured_singletons_tribulationis.bed caenorhabditis_briggsae tribulationis_briggsae.psl --bedType 4
halLiftover evolver_Caenorhabditis.hal --outPSLWithName caenorhabditis_briggsae reconfigured_singletons_briggsae.bed caenorhabditis_nigoni briggsae_nigoni.psl --bedType 4
```

I use system() function from R to open Ubuntu via wsl and run the bash script.

Here is the R code :

```
x <- "wsl --cd /home/lilly/synteny/genes -e ./Step2.sh"
system(x, intern = FALSE,ignore.stdout = FALSE, ignore.stderr = FALSE, wait = TRUE, input = NULL, show.output.on.console = TRUE, minimized = FALSE, invisible = TRUE)
```

Message displayed : gtf2bed, halLiftover commands not found...

My PATH is already set up in Ubuntu for those commands. I tried the command directly in Ubuntu and it works.
So, the problem comes from when I open ubuntu with wsl.

This command alone in cmd windows works well (it open ubuntu and I can run the bash script):

```
wsl --cd /mnt/c/Users/Lilly/OneDrive/Documents/Travail/Synteny_project/
```

BUT, trying to open it and run the bash doesn't work. I think it closes Ubuntu right after openning it and then run the bash script in the windows shell...

I know there is a lot of answered questions about this but I found nothing to solve my problem. Please, help me :(.

Comment: Add `declare -p PATH >&2` _into your script_ so you can compare the PATH the script runs with to the PATH you have in your shell. Remember that variables are inherited from parent processes: If you start R from an IDE and start that IDE from a GUI, it isn't a child of your interactive shell so it doesn't inherit that interactive shell's variables. (This is quite unlike Windows where there's a central store in the registry).

Comment: (Also, it's generally better to provide an _exact_ error message copied-and-pasted instead of an English summary; if there are things like hidden characters in your script, those can manifest in the error message's formatting, but if you don't show that formatting we'd never know).